# jquery scroller with multiple visible items

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroller

I'm trying to build a scroller using jQuery.

The items within the scroller are `display:inline-block` and there can be multiple items visible in the `x` and `y` planes at any given time.

Can anyone help with my scroller?

Here is a jsfiddle with what I currently have. The animated sliding isnt working. I'm trying to make all of the contents slide together outside of the wrapper while the next page of items slide in.

http://jsfiddle.net/GR9ZR/

```
if (~~ (counter / totalVisible) == currentPage) {
    item.show();
    item.animate({
        "left": -(item.position().left)
    });
} else {
    item.animate({
        "left": -(item.position().left)
    });
    item.hide();
}
```

Comment: So, reinventing the wheel? Consider using: http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll

Comment: I'm aware that there are a million scrollers available. Mine has more functionality than the standard ones which is why I am creating a custom scroller.

Comment: Okey, good to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to animate the position, in your CSS you must give the element you are trying to animate a property of `position: relative;`.

Consider a simple example, in which I want to animate a block to move right, when I click on the document page.

Codepen sketch: http://cdpn.io/vdCth

**HTML**

```
<div class='item'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('html').on('click', function(){
  $('.item').animate({
    left: "+=50"
  }, 200, function(){
  });
});
```

Now remove the `position: relative;` from your CSS, and you will see the animation no longer occurs, as demonstrated in this fork: http://cdpn.io/LcakK

Hope that helps.